# Casting an object using the "as" keyword returns null

Tags: c#, casting

Here are my classes definitions:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity : ...
public partial class AbstractContactEntity : AbstractEntity, ...
public sealed class EntityCollectionProxy<T> : IList<T>, System.Collections.IList 
where T : AbstractEntity
```

Now I get an object from a delegate and I want to cast it, and it doesn't work as I expect it to.

```
var obj = resolver.DynamicInvoke (this.entity);
var col = obj as EntityCollectionProxy<AbstractEntity>;
```

`obj` is of type `EntityCollectionProxy<AbstractContactEntity>`.

But `col` is null.
If I try the regular casting (var col = `(Entity...) obj`) I get an exception.

I would expect that it work since the types are coherent. 
What do I miss?

Comment: Can you find one question that asks the same as mine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are not the same types. It is the same as with `List<string>` and `List<int>`: They also can't be casted to one another. That `AbstractContactEntity` is a `AbstractEntity` doesn't change this.
Extracting an interface from `EntityCollectionProxy<T>` and making it [covariant](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) doesn't work either, because you want to implement `IList<T>` which means you have input paramaters and return values of type `T` which prevents covariance.

The only possible solution is the following:

```
var tmp = (EntityCollectionProxy<AbstractContactEntity>)obj;
var col = tmp.Select(x => (AbstractEntity)x);
```

`col` will be of type `IEnumerable<AbstractEntity>`. If you want to have a `EntityCollectionProxy<AbstractEntity>`, you need to create a new one:

```
var result = new EntityCollectionProxy<AbstractEntity>(col);
```

This assumes that your `EntityCollectionProxy<T>` class has a constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`.
But beware, this will be a NEW instance and not the same as returned by `resolver.DynamikInvoke`.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know the generic type `T`, so I can't can it as I say

Comment: I did `(obj as List<object>).Select(x => (AbstractEntity) x)` but it's not the best way to do it I guess

Comment: Jonas: I don't think this will work either. You could do the following: `var col = (obj as IEnumerable).Cast<AbstractEntity>();`